# Writing a windows program with updating, Permission problems

Tags: c, windows, nsis, uac

I want to create a program `Foo.exe` with error logging into `foo.log`. That program is installed (NSIS Installer) into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Foo\`. During installation NSIS added a shortcut (`CreateShortCut "$SMSTARTUP\Foo.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Foo.exe"`) to start `Foo.exe` when windows starts.

- When windows executes my program after startup it starts my program with "non-administrative rights.". So my program can not edit `C:\Program Files (x86)\Foo\foo.log`. Workaround for that is to store editable files in another directory e.g. in `$APPDATA`.
- But here come's the real problem: I added a update function into my program which works in the following way:

  - download the new binary and save as `FooNew.exe`. This file does not have any permissions (explicitly not the execute-flag).
  - create a self-copy with execute permission: `FooCopy.exe`
  - After starting it, `FooCopy.exe` opens `FooNew.exe` and writes it content into `Foo.exe`. Now, `Foo.exe` is updated and has the execute-permission.
  - `FooCopy.exe` will be removed.

So I have not testet the updating but most likely it wont work. I assume that `Foo.exe` can not create files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Foo\` so the updating fails at point 1.

An idea is to save `Foo.exe` not in `C:\Program Files (x86)\` but in `$APPDATA`. So the program has all needed rights. The question is starting that program: It is compiled for 32-bit. Is it possible to have a "launcher" `C:\Program Files (x86)\Foo\launcher.exe` which starts the real application in `$APPDATA`?

That's confused, isn't it? How could I change the auto-update procedure so that UAC will not kick me?

As an example I see `firefox.exe`. How does it updating, thus, writing directly into `C:\Program Files (x86)\...` when normally *no one* could write into that directory without prompting the user.

Chris

Comment: When the software is initially installed, it needs to install a service to be responsible for the automatic updates.  Don't configure the service to automatically start, but configure it so that it can be started without admin privilege.  Make sure the service properly verifies that the update is genuine (e.g., by verifying that it is signed with your certificate) before installing it.

Comment: You mean a service `FooUpdater.exe` which will be executed without admin privilege? But how can that service modify files like `Foo.exe` in the ProgramFiles-directory?
I don't know very much about code-signing, so do I have to sign my code for that? Please be more detailed for me…

Comment: No, I mean a service that runs *with* admin privilege.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox uses a NT service. Services normally run as SYSTEM so it can copy files anywhere and Mozilla configures their service so it can be **started** by a normal user.

It does not make sense to have a launcher in program files and the main app in appdata, you might as well do a per user install in that case (Like Chrome etc).

I assume your application is not a web-browser so keeping it up to date is probably not that critical. I would suggest that your updater just checks for updates and if there is a update you can spawn yourself again (or the main updater?) as Administrator using UAC and then do the update.

Comment: But my program runs in background without gui. So the user does not see anything and should not annoyed with update UAC confirm popups. Keeping my program up to date is important and i don't know at this time how often a update will coming out. My vision is that the user installs the programm and does not see it running. He will see the results in a web portal.

Comment: Those are basically your 3 options: 1) Install per user in $localappdata\Programs. 2) UAC prompt when a new update is available. 3) Write a service and/or scheduled task.

Comment: So i have now installed the service via `CreateService()` (needs admin rights). But when i try to `StartService()` from a program without admin rights(like my `Foo.exe`) I receive an AccessDenied-error. I opened the Service-Handle with `SERVICE_START` and created the service with `SERVICE_DEMAND_START`. But you said that I can start the service as a normal user.

Comment: I said "Mozilla configures their service so it can be started by a normal user", this means you have to change the service ACL after you have created it... (SetServiceObjectSecurity)

Answer (score 0):

Your *"updating"* process needs to be run with administrative permissions.

If UAC is enabled, then you can ask Windows to launch your updater elevated by passing the **`runas`** verb to `ShellExecute`:

```
Boolean RunAsAdmin(HWND hWnd, String filename, String, parameters)
{
    /*
       See Step 3: Redesign for UAC Compatibility (UAC)
       http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756922.aspx
    */
    ShellExecuteInfo sei;

    ZeroMemory(ref sei, sizeoOf(sei));
    sei.cbSize = sizeof(TShellExecuteInfo);
    sei.Wnd = hwnd;
    sei.fMask = SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT || SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
    sei.lpVerb = "runas";
    sei.lpFile = Filename;
    if (parameters <> '')
        sei.lpParameters = parameters;
    sei.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;

    return ShellExecuteEx(ref sei);
}
```

If UAC is not enabled (e.g. the user is running on Windows XP), the user will have no choice but to logoff and login as a user who *does* have administrative privileges.

> **Note**: Any code released into public domain. No attribution required.